# ComboBox.SelectedText doesn't give me the SelectedText

Tags: c#, winforms, string, combobox

I am building a String and the code looks like

```
String status = "The status of my combobox is " + comboBoxTest.SelectedText
```

I am using WinForm in VS2010

The result looks like

> "The status of my combobox is "

Comment: The ComboBox control will have lost selection when focus is leaved

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I think you want to use

```
String status = "The status of my combobox is " + comboBoxTest.Text
```

SelectedText property from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx)

> Gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a
>   ComboBox.

while Text property from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx)

> Gets or sets the text associated with this control.

Comment: What makes that different than comboBoxTest.SelectedItem.ToString()

Comment: @CocoaDev: SelectedItem is an object and could also be a class, so converting it to string could not be what you need. When you populate a combobox you can set items as classes, so watching at SelectedItem you can do what you please...

Comment: SelectedItem is for when you have some sort of binding (DataSource) associated with the ComboBox. It will be an object, but it can be cast to the underlying data (object) type to which the ComboBox is bound.

Answer (score 19):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx):

> You can use the SelectedText property to retrieve or change the currently selected text in a ComboBox control. However, you should be aware that the selection can change automatically because of user interaction. For example, if you retrieve the SelectedText value in a button Click event handler, the value will be an empty string. This is because the selection is automatically cleared when the input focus moves from the combo box to the button.
>
> When the combo box loses focus, the selection point moves to the beginning of the text and any selected text becomes unselected. In this case, getting the SelectedText property retrieves an empty string, and setting the SelectedText property adds the specified value to the beginning of the text.

Answer (score 14):

I face this problem 5 minutes before.

I think that a solution (with visual studio 2005) is:

```
myString = comboBoxTest.GetItemText(comboBoxTest.SelectedItem);
```

Forgive me if I am wrong.

Comment: That`s exactly it! When we set a class to the datasource, its a common problem to get its text, this solved for me

Comment: Is it possible to give +10? ;) Only way to extract text always. And the way that I extract it from VBA too!

Answer (score 11):

I think you dont need `SelectedText` but you may need

```
String status = "The status of my combobox is " + comboBoxTest.Text;
```

Answer (score 5):

All of the previous answers explain what the OP 'should' do.  I am explaining what the `.SelectedText` property is.

The `.SelectedText` property is not the text in the `combobox`.  It is the text that is highlighted.  It is the same as `.SelectedText` property for a `textbox`.

The following picture shows that the `.SelectedText` property would be equal to "ort".

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To get selected item, you have to use SELECTEDITEM property of comboBox. And since this is an Object, if you wanna assign it to a string, you have to convert it to string, by using ToString() method:

```
string myItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); //this does the trick
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`String status = "The status of my combobox is " + comboBoxTest.text;`

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would approach the problem, assuming you want to change the text of say, a label

```
    private void comboBoxtest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var combotext = comboBoxtest.Text;
        var status = "The status of my combo box is" + combotext;
        label1.Text = status;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you bind your Combobox to something like KeyValuePair, with properties in the constructor like so...:

```
 DataSource = dataSource,
 DisplayMember = "Value",
 ValueMember = "Key"
```

so `dataSource` is of type KeyValuePair...

You end up with having to do this...

```
  string v = ((KeyValuePair)((ComboBox)c).SelectedItem).Value;
```

(I had a Dynamic form - where `c` was of type `Control` - so had to cast it to ComboBox)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know the text in the `ComboBox` with the editable text box (or the `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown` style) you can use this:

```
string str = comboBox.SelectedItem != null ?
                      comboBox.GetItemText(comboBox.SelectedItem) : comboBox.Text;
```

Answer (score -2):

or try this code

```
 String status = "The status of my combobox is " + comboBoxTest.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: No, SelectedItem is the object associated with currently selected item and it could be a class, not necessary a string!!!