# How to replace last comment by SelectedText

Tags: c#, winforms

im working on a editor and i want to replace last comment after the intellisense appears .

further more heres the senario,

i got richtextbox(rtb) which served as the code-editor, and a hidden combobox(lb) which served as the intellisense . everytime i type words from richtextbox(rtb), sample i type "as", combobox will appear (like a intellisense) with keywords that starts from "as" .

all functions are working now except for after i select an item from combobox

```
sample string(combo box items): asd, asdf, asdfg .
```

then suppose to be i type as in richtextbox then i select 'asd' from combobox, then when i press enter the output would be:

> as asd

instead of:

> as (only)

further more heres my keyevents code:

```
 void lb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            lb.Visible = false;
            lb.Items.Clear();
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            int start = 0, end = 0;
            String line = rtb.Text.Substring(start, start - end);
            int index = start;

            string comment = line.Substring(index);
            rtb.SelectedText = lb.SelectedText.ToString();

        }
    }
```

note: i just write:

> rtb.SelectedText = comment + " " + lb.SelectedText.ToString();

for now to see some other function but that line was i the one i want to fix . also i even try:

```
 rtb.SelectedText = comment - lb.SelectedText.ToString();
```

> but it says Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

really thanks for the help in advance .

parameter:

```
if (token == "letterA" || token.StartsWith("Ab") || token.StartsWith("ab") || token.StartsWith("AB"))
            {
                int length = line.Length - (index - start);
                string commentText = rtb.Text.Substring(index, length);
                rtb.SelectionStart = index;
                rtb.SelectionLength = length;
                lb.Visible = true;

                KeyWord keywordsHint = new KeyWord();

                foreach (string str in keywordsHint.ab)
                {
                    lb.Items.Add(str);
                    lb.SelectedIndex = lb.FindStringExact(str);
                }
                //token.Replace(lb.SelectedText,"");
            }
```

Comment: Its a bit hard to tell as the question is quite confusing, but try this `rtb.SelectedText = comment.Replace(lb.SelectedText,"");`

Comment: no change but still thanks for the suggestion ...

Comment: parameter added hope you could help me :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this question/answer might be the problem:

[ComboBox.SelectedText doesn't give me the SelectedText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194171/combobox-selectedtext-doesnt-give-me-the-selectedtext)

Try using:

rbt.**SelectedText** = comment + " " + lb.**Text**

instead of SelectedText.

Comment: it cant be if i try it all text in rtb will be all replace and deleted

Comment: Oh I see, sorry! So if I understand correctly, you were expecting "as asd" and the result was simply "as". Maybe you could leave the rbt.SelectedText and use lb.Text?

Comment: i even use this: rtb.SelectedText = lb.SelectedText.ToString(); ... but result was just asasd no change also :(