# Can't save selected Combobox Item because SelectedText is empty String. Why?

Tags: c#, combobox

I try to save a selected comboBox Item and load it to be selected on next program start. I already tried to use SelectedIndex to save it, but its a bad idea because the Index can change in a new session. So i want to use SelectedText to save the selected Item (COM Port).
But when I save it, and look into the file, its just empty. It doesn't save the text displayed in the Combobox. Why does this happen?
Here is my code.

```
        //Load Com Port List into comboBoxes
        string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        foreach (var portName in portNames)
        {                
            comboBox2.Items.Add(portName);
        }
```

Then I select a COM port from the ComboBox, and want to save it.

```
File.WriteAllText("portsave1", textBox18.Text + "+" + comboBox2.SelectedText);
```

But, `comboBox2.SelectedText` is just an empty string, when I look in the save file. Why?!

So when I want to load it by using following code, it doesn't work.

```
comboBox2.SelectedIndex = comboBox2.FindStringExact(comport);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ComboBox.SelectedText doesn't give me the SelectedText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194171/combobox-selectedtext-doesnt-give-me-the-selectedtext)

Comment: Are you quite certain you're using WPF? The WPF ComboBox does not have a property called SelectedText.

Comment: I think what you want is combobox.Text

Comment: When I use this, I get that text that is displayed in the combobox. But when I want to load it after restarting the program, it doesn't work...

Comment: you might try use selecteditem but convert it to a string.  Does it let you do var name = combobox2.SelectedItem as string;?

Comment: Have you tried googling for how to work with winforms? https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwixp9qvs9nTAhUI1ywKHROeAREQtwIILTAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DNkO70veMBR8&usg=AFQjCNGEkPsMw616z_82mtyK8TS2SVTIpQ&sig2=ikI3WqVqsmCV9hnvTZIMvg

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OK, Thank you at all, I solved the problem. All your Code is correct and there are many way's, like `comboBox.Text`, `comboBox.Item` to save it.... My problem was that, I saved it twice, once after connecting to the scale and once when the Form is closing... And when Form was closing it wrote the selected index into the file so that is why it couldn't work. I didn't noticed that and was wondering why its not working. Sorry, and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()` since you're adding `Items` during what I assuming is initialization.

Comment: I get an exception when trying to save comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()

Comment: What kind of exception do you get? `SelectedItem` will be `null` if no item is selected.

Comment: You should be able to check if SelectedItem == null. Or, if the DropDownBox.DropDownStyle == DropDownList then you can just set the SelectedIndex to 0 after you add the items to the DropDownList.

Comment: Paste the exception you are receiving in the comments.

Comment: 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

Comment: @SardarAgabejli, is your save destination `"portsave1"` a variable? If so, take that our of quotes. If it is not a variable try using a fully qualified path. Also, what event are you saving on? Selection change?

Comment: It is a file, but I don't think that the problem is because of wrong saving procedure... Because the other value is written to file correctly...

Comment: This seems redundant, but copy and paste this over what you currently have: `File.WriteAllText("portsave1", textBox18.Text + "+" + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
```