# C# show MessageBox based on Combobox SelectedText

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, messagebox, selectedtext

How do I show a messagebox based on the various SelectedText in the Combobox? It currently just returns a NULL value when running.

I need to show the **specific messagebox** for each Combobox Text as once I can do this then depending on the SelectedText different SQL Connections will be used and Queries run.

I've included my code below. After some research it seems that the SelectedText control will always return a null value as it loses focus. How do I get around this?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(comboSelectServer.SelectedText == "SERV1")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SERV1");
        }
       else if(comboSelectServer.SelectedText == "SERV2")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SERV2");
        }
       else if(comboSelectServer.SelectedText == "SERV3")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SERV3");
        }
    }
```

Comment: u could try `SelectedIndex` instead of `SelectedText`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ComboBox.SelectedText doesn't give me the SelectedText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194171/combobox-selectedtext-doesnt-give-me-the-selectedtext)

Comment: @defaultlocale that doesn't answer my question. I need to show specific message boxes based on the text selected in the combobox, this is why I'm using and if. Once i've cracked this then the plan is to have specific sql connections and statements running instead of the message boxes

Comment: @WHoward Sounds like a great plan! But for now, you're asking, I quote: `SelectedText control will always return a null value as it loses focus. How do I get around this?` This question was already asked and answered here. You might want to fix the problem with `SelectedText` first and then move on to the rest of your project.

Comment: @defaultlocale thanks for the help, got it all sorted using SelectedIndex

Comment: @WHoward I did virtually nothing here, so you don't really need to thank me :) Glad you have it resolved! Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
if (comboSelectServer.Text == "SERV1")
{
    MessageBox.Show("SERV1");
}
else if (comboSelectServer.Text == "SERV2")
{
    MessageBox.Show("SERV2");
}
else if (comboSelectServer.Text == "SERV3")
{
    MessageBox.Show("SERV3");
}
```

However, this is easier...

```
if (comboSelectServer.SelectedIndex == 0) //SERV1
{
    MessageBox.Show("SERV1");
}
else if (comboSelectServer.SelectedIndex == 1) //SERV2
{
    MessageBox.Show("SERV2");
}
else if (comboSelectServer.SelectedIndex == 2) //SERV3
{
    MessageBox.Show("SERV3");
}
```

Comment: I'd tried the second option but kept the ' marks around the 0,1,2..silly me! Thank you for showing me the correct way

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like this

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(comboSelectServer.SelectedItem.ToString()== "SERV1")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("SERV1");
    }
   else if(comboSelectServer.SelectedItem.ToString()== "SERV2")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("SERV2");
    }
   else if(comboSelectServer.SelectedItem.ToString()== "SERV3")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("SERV3");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not simply do:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(comboSelectServer.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```