# IF condition AND / OR logic fails - c#

Tags: c#

I have 2 combobox and 7 textboxes.

The logic if the user provides input as 0 in all the textboxes and has selected the Leave or Holiday in the combox box then the condition should satisfy.

If they selected someother item in the combo box apart from the Holiday/Leave. It should throw the else part.

I have  written below condition in c# but eventhough all the conditions are satisfied the code executes only the else condition.

```
 if (((comboBox3.SelectedText == "Leave") || 
     (comboBox3.SelectedText == "Holiday")) && 
     textBox2.Text != "0" && 
     textBox3.Text != "0" && 
     textBox4.Text != "0" && 
     textBox5.Text != "0" && 
     textBox6.Text != "0" && 
     textBox7.Text != "0" && 
     textBox10.Text != "0")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sucess");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Select Leave/Holiday since all the provided Data is 0");
}
```

EDIT:

As per the request, the output is:

State

0
0
0
0
0
0
0

Comment: "if the user provides input as 0 in all the textboxes" The condition `textBox7.Text != "0"` checks that the user does *not* provide zero.

Comment: OT I hope your real code doesn't use "textBox2" etc, but a more descriptive name. Your future self will thank you for it!

Comment: Replace != with ==.

Comment: What happened to textBox 8 and 9?

Comment: What's with all the downvotes? This seems like a reasonable question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (((comboBox3.SelectedText == "Leave") || 
     comboBox3.SelectedText == "Holiday")) && 
     textBox2.Text == "0" && 
     textBox3.Text == "0" && 
     textBox4.Text == "0" && 
     textBox5.Text == "0" && 
     textBox6.Text == "0" && 
     textBox7.Text == "0" && 
     textBox10.Text == "0")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sucess");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Select Leave/Holiday since all the provided Data is 0");
}
```

---

Replace your code with this and add the result from the Output window/MessageBox to your question above

```
if (((comboBox3.SelectedText == "Leave") || 
     comboBox3.SelectedText == "Holiday")) && 
     textBox2.Text == "0" && 
     textBox3.Text == "0" && 
     textBox4.Text == "0" && 
     textBox5.Text == "0" && 
     textBox6.Text == "0" && 
     textBox7.Text == "0" && 
     textBox10.Text == "0")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Success");
}
else
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("State");
    sb.AppendLine(comboBox3.SelectedText);
    sb.AppendLine(textBox2.Text);
    sb.AppendLine(textBox3.Text);
    sb.AppendLine(textBox4.Text);
    sb.AppendLine(textBox5.Text);
    sb.AppendLine(textBox6.Text);
    sb.AppendLine(textBox7.Text);
    sb.AppendLine(textBox10.Text);
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}
```

---

Ok. You're using combobox1.SelectedText, which is empty!

Try using combobox1.Text instead ...

```
if (((comboBox3.Text == "Leave") || 
     comboBox3.Text == "Holiday")) && 
     textBox2.Text == "0" && 
     textBox3.Text == "0" && 
     textBox4.Text == "0" && 
     textBox5.Text == "0" && 
     textBox6.Text == "0" && 
     textBox7.Text == "0" && 
     textBox10.Text == "0")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Success");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Select Leave/Holiday since all the provided Data is 0");
}
```

Comment: Hi the issue still exists, I have provided all the textboxes as 0 and  selected Leave in the combobox but even now only the else part is executed.

Comment: See my update..

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Updated the answer!

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. What is the diff btw selectedText and Text?

Comment: Glad it worked! Take a look at this SE answer ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/10194234/5040941

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the user "dasblinkenlight", your code, in the actual state, translate as:
"If the user select Leave or Holiday and ALL inputs are DIFFERENT than 0, then 'Success'."

But your business logic state that "If the user select Leave or Holiday and ALL inputs are EQUAL than 0, then 'Success'".

Just change the "!=" operator for the "==" operator and you are fine.